Cannot compile ffmpeg with nvdec on Jetson Orin NX
I struggle with compiling ffmpeg for Jetson Orin NX with hardware acceleration enabled
I checked the default package using this command ffmpeg -hwaccels and I saw that only cuda and drm are enabled. I want to enable nvdec
What are my steps:
git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
#Install ffnvcodec
cd nv-codec-headers && sudo make install && cd../

#Clone FFmpeg's public GIT repository.
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg/

#Install necessary packages.
sudo apt-get install build-essential yasm cmake libtool libc6 libc6-dev unzip wget libnuma1 libnuma-dev

#Configure
prefix=/usr/
ccap=75

./configure \
  --prefix="${prefix}" \
  --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/cuda/include' \
  --extra-ldflags='-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64' \
  --nvccflags="-gencode arch=compute_${ccap},code=sm_${ccap} -O2" \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-decoder=aac \
  --enable-decoder=h264 \
  --enable-decoder=h264_cuvid \
  --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
  --enable-indev=lavfi \
  --enable-encoder=libx264 \
  --enable-encoder=h264_nvenc \
  --enable-demuxer=mov \
  --enable-muxer=mp4 \
  --enable-filter=scale \
  --enable-filter=testsrc2 \
  --enable-protocol=file \
  --enable-protocol=https \
  --enable-gnutls \
  --enable-shared \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-cuda-nvcc \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-nvenc \
  --enable-cuvid \
  --enable-nvdec

#Compile
make -j 8

#Install the libraries.
sudo make install

and at the end when I execute ffmpeg -hwaccels again I see only cuda and drm

ffmpeg version N-117456-gbd6283342c Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/ --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --nvccflags='-gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -O2' --disable-doc --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264_cuvid --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-encoder=h264_nvenc --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=testsrc2 --enable-protocol=file --enable-protocol=https --enable-gnutls --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libx264 --enable-nvenc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvdec
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  avcodec     configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  avformat    configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  avdevice    configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  avfilter    configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  swscale     configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  swresample  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
  postproc    configuration: --prefix= --nvccflags='-gencode arch=compute_,code=sm_ -O2' --disable-doc --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264_cuvid --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-encoder=h264_nvenc --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=testsrc2 --enable-protocol=file --enable-protocol=https --enable-gnutls --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-nvenc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvdec --enable-version3
  libavutil      59. 42.100 / 59. 41.100
  libavcodec     61. 22.100 / 61. 21.100
  libavformat    61.  9.100 / 61.  9.100
  libavdevice    61.  4.100 / 61.  4.100
  libavfilter    10.  6.100 / 10.  6.100
  libswscale      8.  5.100 /  8.  4.100
  libswresample   5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libpostproc    58.  4.100 / 58.  2.100
Hardware acceleration methods:
cuda
drm

What else I should do to be able to add nvdec in Hardware acceleration methods

Read the Docs again.  I believe you forgot to Install ffnvcodec before cloning the public repository
